# Magento, filters not working in "shop by" left menu

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Hello i'm having a problem with magento 1.9.1.0, i've created a main category with 2 subcategory. I've set the main category to Anchor -> Yes. The problem is that the "Shop by" left navigation menu doesn't work, it works only if i visit the maincategory.html___store=default,
i'm getting frustrated, any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you Reindex? `System > Index Management` then select all & Reindex all data